# CSS3 glowing menu

Tags: css

I just visited this [website](http://www.samsung.com/in/#mobile-devices-home) , where I came acros this glowing menu (bottom one), my guess to it is that it might be possible through `CSS3` shadow effect or something similar.
Can anybody let me know as to how can I achieve such effect for my current project.
I tried searching for some tutorials online but could not find any.
Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you look at the website you posted and see how it's done? That's the beauty of the web, you can see how things are made.

Comment: using firebug in Firefox, F12 in IE9, web inspector in Safari etc... you can see the style used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS3's `box-shadow` is what you want to look at: http://jsfiddle.net/3rSbP/

Comment: thanks for that understood it a bit closely , another thing is how to produce oval sort of shape while hovering.Any ideas

Comment: If you want to have it truly oval, you need to use radial-gradiant, see http://jsfiddle.net/3rSbP/1/ for an update.

Answer (score 2):

What they do is they use this image

[image: Samsung background image]

and move it behind the menu items (*as the background of their container*)

---

**To achieve something similar with CSS**

Use `border-radius:50%` on a square element to make it circular and then apply `box-shadow` for the soft fade ..

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/kt4yb/

---

***Hint***: read the source and their styles to understand (*use firebug and other web debugging tools*)

Answer (score 1):

it is jst changing the background image ...you can see that in index.css there is a css class  hovermenu0, hovermenu1, .... set the background image, and these classes apply on UL like.

```
     <ul class="depth1 hoverMenu0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a modern browser you can directly check out what mechanism they are employing to achieve a particular design.

- On Chrome and Opera, right click and choose 'Inspect Element'.
- On Firefox, install the Firebug plug-in and use that.
- On Safari, use Web Inspector.

I might be wrong, but at a first glance it appears that they are using different static background images and changing them in response to events using js (look for *Event Listeners* in Chrome). But it is possible to do this in CSS3 without using static images, albeit slightly more elaborately.